# Syntactic/semantic difference between struct declaration styles

Tags: go

Any difference between these two declarations?

```
type Foo = struct {
    F string `zoom:"1"`
}
```

and

```
type Foo struct {
    F string `zoom:"1"`
}
```

they both compile and seem to work the same.

Comment: Read Alias declaration under https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd one, it's an example of struct declaration.

```
type Foo struct {
    F string `zoom:"1"`
}
```

---

And the 1st one, it is usage example of go1.9 new feature: [type aliases](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#language).

A new type `Foo` is created. It's an alias of an anonymous struct.

```
type Foo = struct {
    F string `zoom:"1"`
}
```

The type aliases syntax can be used to define a struct. In example above, it's generating an equivalent result like `type Foo struct`.

But, the original purpose of type alias is to make an alias from defined type.

In example below, a new type called `Bar` is created and it's an alias of `Foo` struct.

```
type Foo struct {
    F string `zoom:"1"`
}
type Bar = Foo
```

Comment: yeah it's a type alias, but weird that it would let you "alias" something that hasn't already been declared, if you follow.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman I think we can use this term: an alias of anonymous struct